# How to write PHP code inside a variable output?

Tags: php

I have a user table where I have to display a delete button and I need to make sure the current user cannot delete themselves.
In order to do that, I wrote some code as shown below, but it doesn't work.

The user table appears with the delete button in *all* the users, but I need to make sure the current user cannot delete their own user account.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$output .='<tr>  
            <td>'.$row["user_id"].'</td>  
            <td>'.$row["fullname"].' </td>
            <td>'.$row["user_role"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["password"].'</td> 
            <td>'.$row["branch_id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["registered_date"].'</td>  
            <td>
                <button id="'.$row["user_id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs edit_data"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></button>&nbsp;
            if('.$_SESSION['username'].'!='.$row["username"].') {
            <a id="'.$row["user_id"].'"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> } </td> 
        </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: why  is jquery tagged?? removing it now.

Comment: need some answer bro??

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute PHP in a string, you need to split your string creation.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .='<tr>  
                <td>'.$row["user_id"].'</td>  
                <td>'.$row["fullname"].' </td>
                <td>'.$row["user_role"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["password"].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row["branch_id"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["registered_date"].'</td>  
                <td>
                    <button id="'.$row["user_id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs edit_data"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></button>';
                    if ($_SESSION['username'] != $row["username"]) {
                        $output .= '<a id="'.$row["user_id"].'"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>';
                    }
    $output .= '</td></tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: @sagarneupane don't forget the green check:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you output your variable right after the loop - you can do the following

```
<table>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['user_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['fullname']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['user_role']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['password']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['branch_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['registered_date']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['username'] != $row['username'])
        {
        ?>
         <a id="<?=$row['user_id']; ?>"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```